# Simple Injector .NET Standard NuGet package PDB

Tags: simple-injector, debug-symbols

Is it possible to obtain a PDB file for the Simple Injector NuGet package?
I could not find it and ended up building the simpleinjector.dll from the sources. Then updating my own projects to reference that dll.

Comment: Why do you need them?

Comment: open a [support issue](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues) an request that they add [source link](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#using-sourcelink) and upload PDB package to [nuget symbol server](https://blog.nuget.org/20181116/Improved-debugging-experience-with-the-NuGet-org-symbol-server-and-snupkg.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Injector does not publish its PDB files. It is, therefore, impossible to obtain them. You will have to build them yourself.

This decision, however, might change in the future.